# Show & Download only 1st image from Flexslider on mobile

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, flexslider

I'm trying to figure out a way to programmatically show only the 1st image from each slideshow on my web site on small viewports - say less than 640px. I have about 20 different slideshows in all, so I'm trying to figure out how to do this site-wide. I've tried a couple different CSS ways, like setting all the li's except for firstchild to display: none - but the problem is that the images still get loaded, so it sort of defeats the purpose of having a light weight version for mobile. I guess I could kill flexslider outright, then go in and add a new div with the one image I want that only displays on mobile, but that seems like a huge PITA.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I guess it would have to be a jQuery thing, but I don't even know where to begin and I don't want to start messing around with jquery.flexslider.js and end up just breaking it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Well seems nobody else knew what to do either.  Just thought I would post my solution, in case it helps someone else.  You need to use modernizr to do it this way, and add a class="keep" to the li of the slide you want to keep.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//shows only 1st image from flexslider on mobile
if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 767px)')) {
    $(".flexslider li:not(.keep)").remove();
    $( ".flexslider" ).removeClass( "flexslider" ).addClass( "noslider" );
} else {
    //these are my flexslider settings, use yours
    $(window).load(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade", 
        animationSpeed: 3500,
        directionNav: false,
        controlNav: false,
        smoothHeight: false,
        slideshow: false,
        useCss: false,
        start: function(slider){
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
       }
     });
 });
}
</script>
```

Then just add styles for .keep and .noslider to your css!